# Serializing data with Google Protobuf in Python

Tags: python, serialization, protocol-buffers

I have a text file with contents like this (format ):

```
Alice:ECE505,56:HIS230,78:REC345,98
Bob:MATH300,78:IN121,79:LEC091,23:ARC,32:WER720,67
```

I would like to add each class name and score to its perspective person. 
So far I have something like this:

```
all_stu = record_pb2.Result()
person = all_stu.student.add()
cl = person.courses.add()

with open(textfile, "r") as readfile:
    txt = readfile.read()
    for line in txt.split('\n'):
        segment = line.split(':')
        person.name = segment[0]

        classes = segment[1:]

        #I have tried this but it only returns the last class and score 
        for c in classes:
            cname, score = c.split(',')
            cl.name = cname
            cl.score = score
```

I know my loop only returns the last class name and score but how do I store each of the classes and scores for the respective person/line with Google Protobuf?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to add each each person you read from the file. Next you need to add each class  your find in the person object. You now only create those objects once and thus you overwrite them all the time.

```py
all_stu = record_pb2.Result()
person = all_stu.student.add()

with open(textfile, "r") as readfile:
    txt = readfile.read()
    for line in txt.split('\n'):
        segment = line.split(':')

        person = all_stu.student.add()
        person.name = segment[0]

        classes = segment[1:]

        #I have tried this but it only returns the last class and score 
        for c in classes:
            cl = person.courses.add()
            cname, score = c.split(',')
            cl.name = cname
            cl.score = score
```

Here I do make the assumption that courses is a repeated field.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was defining `cl = person.courses.add()` outside the loop. This makes a lot more sense!!